# Ao clicar no meu submit, a função do php está abrindo meu arquivo

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte arquivo chamado teste3.php:

```
<form action="cadastros.php" method="post">

<label for="latitude" hidden>Latitude:</label>
<input id="latMap" hidden name="latitude"/>

<label for="longitude" hidden>Longitude:</label>
<input id="lngMap" hidden name="longitude"/>

<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="inserir">

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Quando eu clico no submit, essa função é chamada no meu arquivo cadastros.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
    if($_POST['acao'] == "inserir"){
    cadastraLatLong();
  }
}

function abrirBanco(){
    $conexao = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "cademeupet");
    return $conexao;
}

function cadastraLatLong(){
  $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
  $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

  $banco = abrirBanco();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO marcadores (id, descricao, lat, lng, tipo) VALUES (NULL, 'teste', '$latitude', '$longitude', 'testetipo')";
  $banco->query($sql);
  $banco->close();
  header('Location: teste3.php');
}
```

Quando clico no botão submit, o arquivo cadastros.php é aberto e mostrado o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Certeza absoluta que o PHP está instalado na sua máquina?

Comment: sim, eu uso o xampp, ele instala o php, eu também consigo acessar o phpmyadmin...

Comment: Quando dou php -v, é mostrado PHP 7.2.10

Comment: é aberto com <?php

Answer (score 0):

O caminho especificado na barra de endereço é do arquivo na maquina, dessa forma ele não roda o arquivo no servidor.

Você precisa usar o caminho do localhost definido pelo xamp.

**Exemplo**:
localhost/cadastro.php

Comment: Troquei para:  <form action="127.0.0.1/cademeupet/cadastros.php" method="post">

mas quando clico no submit, ainda é aberto o arquivo cadastros.php com o seguinte conteudo:

query($sql); $banco->close(); header('Location: teste3.php'); } ?>

Comment: O action continua como cadastros.php. Você vai colocar o caminho no navegador como o do localhost, como exemplifiquei. Sempre que o site está rodando no xampp vc executa no localhost.